# Why use a cache

Tags: angularjs

In [`AngularJS`](https://angularjs.org/) you can create a cache.

This is essentially nothing more than the equivalent of an `ArrayList<T>` in Java where you can add/remove items. In Javascript though, you have push and pop to add/remove stuff from an array.

So why would you want to use AngularJS' cache?

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24cacheFactory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You do it for the purpose of reuse and abstraction.**

The cache will only exist once, but if you implement it in every controller or service, you are duplicating the same code over and over, making it harder to maintain.

It's also an abstraction, you are basicly creating a **module with an interface**, which makes your services independent from the implementation behind it.

In example, you could have a cache item that expires, you could either a write the code/logic to remove the expired ones in every single service, or you could have it in a single module you call cache. This way you are reusing code, and making it easy to maintain.

**Wether you use theirs, or make your own doesn't matter, the principals are the same.**

One reason to use the Angular cache, is so that you don't have to write the same boiler plate everyone else have already implemented a thousand times. You can go straight to your ***domain and business logic***

---

You also get certain benifits from using a Cache Module.

1. You don't have to care about the implementation behind the interface. (Program against an interface, not an implementation).
2. You can inject a different module with different logic behind it, but with the same interface, with DI.
3. It's easy to maintain.
4. You can easily extend and expand it, eg. add expiration.
5. It's easier to make test stubs (see point 2.).
6. You can easily reuse the module.
7. The logic is in it's rightful place, and not scattered around.

Comment: Array.push, pop and splice accomplish the same thing as the cache service, so I don't really see anything in your argument that makes a compelling case to use it. It seems like the cache function is just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Why use IList<T> when you can just use ArrayList<T>? Also the Angular cache, can get items by their keys, the array cannot. And as a third argument, what if you want to add a new function? For example if you want to add expiration, where would you put it?

Comment: "For example if you want to add expiration, where would you put it?" - Where would you put it in Angular? If you're going to expand the functionality, you can just as well as create a class or better yet, use a framework specifically designed for caching such as breezejs

Comment: The angular cache gives you more than what an array gives you, it gives you a small layered of BL on top. You use it because it gives you the basic functionality you need. If you can't see that it is useful for you, then don't use it.